# How to refactor code when I want to use return value of function as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, refactoring

I want to refactor the following function:

```
export const getUserData = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  
   const client = getClient()

   const nameResult = await client.rpc.make('user/getName', user)

   let nameStatus

   if (!nameResult) {
      // Throw error
   } else {
      // Do something useful
   }

   const isNice = await client.rpc.make('user/isNice', user);   
   // ... Fetching various other data ...
}
```

I want to get the whole bit that is about getting the user's name, and want to put it in a different function, so my getUserData function will be more readable. I'm doing a lot of other things similar to this, and I want each of them to eventually be in their own corresponding function. So I create my dedicated getName function:

```
const client = getClient()

const getName = async (user) => {
    const nameResult = await client.rpc.make('user/getName', user)

    let nameStatus

    if (!nameResult) {
       // Throw error
    } else {
       // Do something useful
    }

    return nameStatus
}

export const getUserData = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   const nameStatus = await getName(user)

   const isNice = await client.rpc.make('user/isNice', user);   
   // ... Fetching various other data ...
}
```

Now my goal is achieved, my getUserData function is shorter. But there is another problem now. Both functions need the client. Before refactoring, I got it in the function body, so there was no problem. But now I want to use it like a global variable, and my functions can not access it. My guess is that the getClient function actually never runs, because I'm only invoking my getUserResult function when I'm using these functions from another file. When the getClient call was in the getUserData function, it was actually invoked, because I called this function from another file, but now it is simply there globally without ever running it. How could I create a global client variable that I can use in all my functions below?

Comment: I don't understand why the global variable doesn't work for you.

Comment: Why doens't the `getClient()` function return when you initialize the global variable?

Comment: @Barmar You are right, I have inserted the line where I invoke the getClient function

Comment: Thank you. I still don't see the problem with the refactored version. The global variable should be initialized

Comment: @Barmar the function doesn't return because I'm not running the file itself, but the exported function

Comment: When you import from a file, it runs the file.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I see. Then I don't understand the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to run getClient function everytime before all the function, then you can convert it into an  IIFE expression, which will get invoked by itself.